# Plane wave basis functions

Tags: plane-waves

When using plane wave basis functions,

**what is the phase of each plane wave?**

Should a one-electron wavefunction looks like $\Phi^k_{\beta}(r) = \sum_{G} c^k_{\beta,G}e^{i((k+G) r + \varphi_G)}$ instead of $\Phi^k_{\beta}(r) = \sum_{G} c^k_{\beta,G}e^{i(k+G) r}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter: the coeficients are supposed to be complex, absorbing the phases.

Comment: Even more, the phase does not affect the plane wave: exp(iφ)exp(ikr) is physically indistinguishable from exp(ikr) itself.

Comment: When solving the eigenvalue problem of the Hamiltonian, are the coefficients complex or real? (The 'could' in the answer is disturbing me.)

Comment: It depends on what problems you are solving @mle, you could met cases where all coefficients are real. But in general (in symbolic calculation), you should treate them as complex, i.e., using their adjoint, not transpose when switch from $\psi$ to $\psi^\ast$.